# Find your market

Tags: lateral-thinking, strategy

There are 100 people from different nationality, gender, profession etc in a ballroom are taken as captives by an underground gang.

Each of captives are given 5 dollar bills.

And said

> After 30 minutes, all of you will be categorized into 3 groups of
>   people.
>
> 1) group with 0 dollars
>
> 2) group with 5 dollars
>
> 3) group with more than 5 dollars
>
> Once categorized,
>
> - We will Kill all those belongs to group 1.
> - We will chop down the hand and legs of those belongs to group 2.
> - We will gift 5 million dollars to those who belongs to group 3 and will be set free

**How do you make it so you end up in the 3rd group?**

Nb:You cannot fight with others to get their money. The gang will kill those who are fighting instantly.

Comment: How do you get more or less money? For instance do they bet or something like that?

Comment: need information ...

Comment: And which group am I in if I end with 3 dollars?

Comment: I believe that the information about different culture of the people is important to achieve your expected solution?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's been abandoned.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry is that a reason? Never seen that before, I just VTC as unclear what you are asking

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil; it's quite common on several other sites, Mathematics for one. It means the user has posted the question, but is no longer interested for some reason. Or they have gone on holdiay.

Comment: @4 Leave Cover: I tried to improve this question so that it won't be not so broad. You can roll back if you think it's not what you intended.

Comment: Is it clear for everyone there (captives) what are the consequences of being placed in a group?

Answer (score 2):

> Do nothing special.
>  1. Each captive has 5 dollars.
>  2. All of them together are considered a group (group of 100 captives).
>  3. The group they make has 500 dollars (100 people with 5 dollars each).

So you belong to a "group with more than 5 dollars". Nothing to worry about.

Comment: If this is not the intended answer, this should be

Answer (score 1):

Well it doesn't say what you do in that 30 minutes, but if you want to end up with more than 5 dollars then you could:

> 1. Nick someone's money
> 2. Leave the ballroom, go home and get more money before coming back, or simply start with more money
> 3. Make a bet with someone of 5 dollars that you will end in group 2. Then at the end you will be placed in group 2 but the person has to give you their 5 dollars so you will be moved to group 3.

Plan 3 is the sort of answer you were probably looking for more, although I would probably go with the Plan 1 :P

Answer (score 0):

Since it is so open ended, I would:

> Offer shares of the reward I assume I will earn for being in group 3 for a dollar, so anyone willing to give me money to upgrade my grouping gets a cut of the reward. If there isn't any reward for being in group 3 (rendering this solution invalid), I'm going home to do something more productive with my time.